# Fade in/out Windows Media Player when pressing play/pause button

Tags: windows-media-player

How can I make Windows Media Player fade in/out when I hit the play/pause button wherever I'm in at the song? I'm not talking about cross-fading or transitioning from one song to another.

I want the audio to slowly fade to quiet if it's playing and I press pause, or gradually come back to volume if unpausing it.

Comment: Have you looked at [this tutorial?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-vista/create-smooth-transitions-between-songs-with-crossfading)

Comment: Yes, but didn't found what I'm looking for.

Comment: From this google search

https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=fade+in+fade+out+windows+media+player+-crossfade

It looks like windows media player doesn't have this feature.  The answer might be deal without it or move media players to one that does

Comment: Winamp does this (it's even enabled by default IIRC). But there's no way to have the same in WMP, unfortunately.